# How tor print the first occurrence if there are more than 1 max values?

Tags: c

So I have to write some code that reads from a file and outputs certain parts of it.

For one part of it, I have to read some values and print out the one that occurs the most.

My problem is that if there are more than 1 values that occur a maximum amount of times (e.g. 5 and 4 both occur 2 times), my code is printing the latter value.

I want to print the first one (in this example, that would be 5). How do I do that?

Here is my code so far;

```
    int find_max(int id[], char poi_names[][51], int num){
     int max_index = 0;
     int max_freq = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i < num -1; i++){
         int freq = 1;
         for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
             if(id[i] == id[j]){
                 freq ++;
             }
         }
         if(max_freq<freq){
             max_index = i;
             max_freq = freq;
         }
     }
     return max_index;
 }
```

Comment: sneaky way: reverse loop direction, from num down to 1. both i and j

Comment: as in `for (i =0; num > 1; i--)`?

Comment: It would make your question clearer if you give the value of the parameters like `id`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `first one`. Is it the first occurence in the array. e.g. if array is `{4,5,5,4}` do you print `4`?

Comment: Yes @RishikeshRaje, sorry for not being clear, but that is what i want

Comment: A reverse loop should work fine, but maybe the problem is hiding in your data. Use `printf("%d %d %d\n", max_freq, i, id[i]);` in your `if(max_freq<freq)` so you may see what happen when the max is updated.

Comment: @AugustinLopez I will give that a try. How would I initialise a reverse loop? I'm not 100% sure as I have not done it before

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < num -1; i++)` become `for(int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--);`. I don't use `for` often (I am more of a `while` person): use `printf` to verify  that the max and min value of `i` are iterated over.

Comment: you can fix your code with one character. change max_freq<freq to max_freq<=freq. this will allow the new ids (that are also max) to replace the lower ids.

Answer (score 0):

Insert another condition if frequency is same as max frequency and in that condition check if the max_index is less than the index, if less than print.

```
else if (max_freq == freq){
    if(max_index > index)
        max_index = index
}
```

I think this should give the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for (max_freq lessthan freq), allow it to replace the id also when (max_freq==freq)... This will allow new values with the same freq to replace the previous maximum.

```
if(max_freq<=freq){
     max_index = i;
     max_freq = freq;
}
```